# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when creating a EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm using the `Spring Framework` in addition with the `spring-data-jpa`. I want to create my `DataSource` and `EntityManagerFactory` promatically by creating the beans because as from my Knowledge it's not possible to use a properties file with all that stuff in a pure Spring context.

Please do not wonder about my configuration if anything doesn't make sense. This is just a bunch of code I got from the internet because I'm not that into hibernate/spring-data-jpa/jpa and how its ever called.

So my problem now is that I want to create my `EntityManagerFactory` but, it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and I have no clue where it gets from and how I get rid of it.

Stack:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [de/nebelniek/BukkitConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at de.nebelniek.Subserver.onEnable(Subserver.java:15) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:370) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:500) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:561) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:475) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:733) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:353) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1230) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:322) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.updateTypeTarget(Indexer.java:903) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.updateTypeTargets(Indexer.java:630) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:1698) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassDescriptor(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:64) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:52) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:147) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:48) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:76) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:107) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:269) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:182) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    ... 21 more
```

My Configuration:

```java
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true); //Auto creating scheme when true
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("de.nebelniek.database.user");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

    private DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mariadb://example.com:3306/database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Also I think it would be very usefull to provide the Entities in `de.nebelniek.database.user`, well I only have one:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CloudUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private UUID uuid;
    private String lastUserName;
    private Date lastLogin;
    private String twitchId;
    private boolean subbed;

}
```

So, with that being said, thanks to anyone helping me. <3

Comment: Maybe related to this? Better to upgrade your version and try. https://github.com/wildfly/jandex/issues/80

Comment: @KishoreBandi I already got the verison 2.2.3.Final as he stated it should be fixed there.

Comment: @JanHerzog Were you able to solve the issue? I have the same issue, that appears only in docker for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I found my problem in guava library.
Just downgraded version of guava to 30.1.1-jre and it works fine.

Reference: https://githubmemory.com/repo/wildfly/jandex/issues/147

Comment: Same for me - however what is the upgrade path?